# Am confused as to why my graph isn't showing up in vega?

Tags: vega-lite

My graph isn't plotting in vega despite no error that i can see? Confused as to why this seems to be the case. I don't quite understand what I would've done wrong for the graph to not appear on the page. This is a template that I downloaded

{
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",

```
"title": {
  "text": "My new Covid Chart",
  "subtitle":"This is my new chart",
  "subtitleFontStyle":"italic",
  "subtitleFontSize":10,
  "anchor": "start",
  "color": "black"
},

 "data": {
  "url": "https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v2/data?areaType=overview&metric=newCasesBySpecimenDate&format=csv",
  "format": {"type": "csv"}
},

 "transform":[
    
    {"filter": {
      "field": "areaName", 
      "oneOf": ["Bristol, City of", "Bolton", "Glasgow City"]}
      }


  ],


"height": 300,
"width": 310,
 
"mark": {"type": "line", "point": false},

"encoding": {

  "x": {
    "field": "date",
    "type": "temporal",
    "title": null,
    "axis": {"grid": false}
  },

  "y": {
    "field": "newCasesByPublishDateRollingRate",
    "type": "quantitative",
    "title": null,
    "axis": {"grid": false}
  },

  "color": {
    "field": "areaName",
    "type": "nominal",
    "scale": {"scheme": "set1"},
    "title": "LEGEND TITLE",
    "legend": {
      "orient": "top-left", 
      "fillColor": "#FcFdFd"}
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You had applied `filter` transform which was not satisfying the criteria and making the data empty. Also the `newCasesByPublishDateRollingRate` field for y-axis used was not present in your data, instead I tried the field `newCasesBySpecimenDate` which worked.
Adding the correct config below or refer the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQmOoLhpQmOAA9MaEAFkAngAJZcAO4mAwm2I0AJjZhIATnqURmKzGv0AVGBoIE2CTBFNzK1g3DxAvJh81ADE5TABlTCM-dDokYShFeO9VOFTZDJoAL3VUAEYABiUkWVg2V30ITFiiqDZBdv0mQSQoAGsQAF8lByRujRAGV0F9LFx8IiQcGko+1zkke1cGCEpZ7uo7SgYxkgAmAnOkAH43OCR-Ixw4AF47OFc9ksADIEHBMK4aFAflFrEgIHAIAAhIzpb5QGhg2QAETmcGBADN2shMD8oBBiEUia4SQsst99OTKZNphg4DQyFg0ABmBpNEAWRz0HmNJTIVwTVCaL61EDCcxFHBsGgVNAE-II1lwVpsBwqsgLbQLAk0OCCBz6c7qJT02VaBBK1z5IpJWqyBiCQTNbTBBZkSEW1DqwSa1lGY2m836WHwxEotFwDFY3FaF0y-QARwYLR8cxopBdpTQ7s93t9UpA-scao1cBZSj6Aw6FZNZsDIDeSAAckgwWmGehZGwECrnZ4oPlaqAuIhZQjMHUpjai+gADIAUQA4uuu9iTP4AJL+DdFNRkbWB0DtU2q9CYNg4IRwAlxE2e2xN-QAYmSUGSDn-KYWUmIA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "My new Covid Chart",
    "subtitle": "This is my new chart",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v2/data?areaType=overview&metric=newCasesBySpecimenDate&format=csv",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "height": 300,
  "width": 310,
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": false},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": null,
      "axis": {"grid": false}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "newCasesBySpecimenDate",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": null,
      "axis": {"grid": false}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "areaName",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"scheme": "set1"},
      "title": "LEGEND TITLE",
      "legend": {"orient": "top-left", "fillColor": "#FcFdFd"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm trying to filter the data so that the graph only displays three cities. For example, Swansea, Aberdeen, and ( Glasgow, City of). I would've thought that by applying filter transform that would filter the data to include those cities.

Comment: ok, even but your data was not having the cities so it was getting empty with filter. Anyways with filter also the graph would not have plotted as the field was improper.

Comment: Surely the data does have the cities though?? That's why i would've thought that filtering by areaname would work. Sorry new to this so still trying to grasp everything.